# How to use std algorithm to replace this for loop?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have:

```
struct A
{
    int index;

    A(): index(0) {}
}
std::vector<A> ManyAs(10, A());
```

And wants to do:

```
for (int i = 0, size = ManyAs.size(); i < size; ++i)
{
    ManyAs[i].index = i;
}
```

I want to do this with std algotrithm, maybe `std::for_each`?

How to do it, thanks!

Comment: I'd leave it like that - you need the loop counter, and the algorithms don't give you one.

Comment: They are vectors, instead of counting you could use pointer arithmetic to get i.

Comment: Why? This is fine the way it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I found my ideal answer:

```
std::for_each(ManyAs.begin(), ManyAs.end(),
    [&](A& a)
    {
        int offset=(&a) - (&ManyAs.front());
        a.index = offset;
    });
```

Actually it's quite similar to Raxvan's answer, but everything is local, which is better imo.

Answer (score 3):

I would do the following way

```
struct A
{
    int index;

    A(): index(0) {}
    A & operator =( int i )
    {
        index = i;
        return ( *this );
    }
};

std::iota( ManyAs.begin(), ManyAs.end(), 0 );
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But in my own opinion it's kind of non-intuitive...but still thanks!

Comment: Agreed.  Now I have to go look at the definition to see what this is really doing.  Complicating simple code isn't a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case, I'd leave the code as it is. Standard library algorithms are best used when you want to apply the *same operation* to all elements of the range. But here, you don't actually apply the same operation, as you assign a different number to each element's index. So a counter-based `for` loop seems to be the most natural solution here.

However, if you really want to use a standard algorithm, you can use a stateful functor:

```
struct Functor
{
  size_t index;
  Functor() : index(0) {}
  void operator() (A &a) { a.index = index++; }
};

std::for_each(ManyAs.begin(), ManyAs.end(), Functor());
```

Comment: Yes you're right, `for_each` is for the same operation, I got it. So maybe a `generate` or `transform`? Is there any more suitable algorithm? By the way, your functor is still a good point, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are two approaces:

```
struct my_functor
{
    my_functor()
        : i(0)
    {
    }
    void operator () (A & a)
    {
        a.index = i++;
    }
    int i;
};
void foo();
{
    //old c++ style
    std::for_each(ManyAs.begin(), ManyAs.end(), my_functor());
}
```

second:

```
//c++11
int i = 0;
std::for_each(ManyAs.begin(), ManyAs.end(), [&](A & a){ a.index = i++; });
```

Comment: You could define `static int i = 0;` inside the lambda itself.

Comment: @Nawaz yes, but i would not recommend that because `i` will never get set to 0 if the code that uses the lambda is reused.